# How asynchronous functions are working inside bcrypt() method in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, bcrypt

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 8;
const plainPassword1 = "12345";
const plainPassword2 = "56789";

const func1 = async (password, plainP) => {
    console.log("hashing password");
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
    console.log(password + ": " + hashedPassword);
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(plainP, hashedPassword);
    if (isMatch === true) {
        return console.log(password + " matches with", plainP);
    }
    console.log(password + " didn't match with " + plainP)
}

func1(plainPassword1, plainPassword2);
func1(plainPassword2, plainPassword2);
```

**Output**

```
hashing password
hashing password
12345: $2b$08$eSDJGsRzKRy9xsKpkQPx6ubEX5EH7w6JdnnMVtZnCoH/kpZ8HkvRi
56789: $2b$08$NRAeOzk6XdiVsVwgxz/s8ugvfSdH9VoAaG.fQLf2WTlIaNi0siQzu
12345 didn't match with 56789
56789 matches with 56789
```

**I want to know that in this case why are we getting both the hash passwords first. I know bcrypt.hash() and bcrypt.compare() are asynchronous functions but I want to know the exact working of the code. I am still new to the concept of asynchronous programming so its little confusing for me.**

Comment: because of `await` keyword which make sure that it doesn't execute next line until the promise is resolved.

Comment: Go through docs for more details 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: In addition to @RahulKumar's comment, defining func1 = async prevents locking of the single-threaded Nodejs event loop by calling a too long synched method within too many synched calls.

Comment: @Rahul Kumar okay so "await" keyword will stop the execution of whole code written after it or it will stop only the execution of that code which is dependent on its result?

Comment: The first time you call `func1` it starts an async operation but does not wait for it. The second `func1` then gets called and both are still executing. If you want them to run in sequence you should `await` each call to `func1`

Answer (score -2):

This does not have to do with asynchronous programming. It is due to bcrypt's hashing algorithm.

Each hash consist of four parts: `$[algorithm]$[cost]$[salt][hash]`. These parts are then used by the compare function to decrypt the hashed value.

You can read more about the algorithm here: [bcrypt hash info](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info)

Comment: Can you please tell me the order of events occurring?